# "SPH" Written in Cylinder section of prescription, along with no axis?

Tags: optometry

I found a glasses prescription, for the Cylindrical section, The left eye has a numerical value, but the right eye simply says: "SPH". Is this taken to mean, that the cylindrical for my right eye, is the same as the Spherical?

Also, AXIS is only defined for one eye, does this mean that the other one is assumed to be zero?

Comment: Generally, this is not the place to ask for personal medical advice - whoever wrote the prescription should have the obligation to explain to you what the prescription says. That said, maybe look up "cylindrical abberration", "spherical abberration" and "astigmatism" (AXIS).

Comment: I edited the question, it is no longer personal medical advice. It is now general medical understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

- "CYL" in Spherical section, means no correction needed
- "SPH" in Cylindrical section, means no correction needed

If AXIS is zero, that is  shorthand way some O.D.'s use to write 180.